# É normal que mais de um módulo seja instalado de uma só vez?

Tags: python

Estou começando a aprender sobre bibliotecas/módulos externos depois de ter aprendido o básico do python e algumas bibliotecas internas e usei `pip install pandas` pra instalar o pandas, mas foram instalados o pandas, o pytz, o six, o numpy e o python-dateutil, tudo de uma pancada só. Queria saber se isso é normal ou se eu fiz algo errado.

Comment: É normal porque o pandas [depende desses outros módulos](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html#dependencies), e o pip já os instala automaticamente (e se eles tiverem outras dependências, estas também são instaladas, etc)

Comment: Brigado, amigo(a) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é normal, visto que o pandas instala as dependências necessárias para o seu funcionamento como podemos ver nesse link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html#dependencies